# MySQL - Keep rows where one entry is a value with multiple occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I'm stuck with this problem, and I guess I'm not good enough in MySQL to solve it by myself.

As an example, let's consider this table :

[image]

Green entries represent the wanted output of my query, only rows where ENTRY_2 is a value with multiple occurrences are kept.

All I tried for now is something like that :

```
select *
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ENTRY_2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

But it's not good for obvious reasons (doesn't even work).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ENTRY_2 IN (
    SELECT ENTRY_2
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY ENTRY_2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 from mytable t2 where t2.entry2 = t.entry2 and t2.entry1 <> t.entry1);
```